# How can I find character being in one factor containing another factor

Tags: r

I would like to find each email containing each name or account, and if the character of account is included in the email, I want to get a logical value. Also, if the email changes like gmail@zzz.com, I want to find out zzz. Here is the data.

| account | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| zzz | zzz | zzz@gmail.com |
| zzz1 | zzz1 | zzz1@gmail.com |
| zzz2 | zzz2 | zzz2@gmail.com |
| zzz3 | zzz3 | zzz3@gmail.com |
| zzz4 | zzz4 | zzz4@gmail.com |
| zzz5 | zzz5 | zzz5@gmail.com |
| zzz6 | zzz6 | zzz6@gmail.com |
| zzz7 | zzz7 | zzz7@gmail.com |
| zzz8 | zzz8 | zzz8@gmail.com |
| zzz9 | zzz9 | zzz9@gmail.com |

I tried two ways seperately, but I got an error.

```
ifelse(df$email %in% df$account, "1", "0")
str_detect(df$email,df$account)
```

Then, how can I know that each row of account is contained in each row of email.

Comment: I think `str_detect(df$account, df$email)` should work?  (Or `grepl()`).  What error did you get?

Comment: I got this message when I used `str_detect`.
Error in UseMethod("type") : 
no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "factor". Also, Warning in grepl(df1$account, df1$email) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used. This appeard when I used `grepl(df$account, df$email)`

Comment: @EdisonThomas Can you provide this data with the factor? You can do `dput()` on your dataframe, then paste the results here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a problem with `as.character()`

```
str_detect(as.character(df$email),as.character(df$account))
```